# Is it possible to deploy to openshift using Circle CI?

Tags: openshift, circleci

Currently learning about CI CD for an upcoming project. Currently our project is being hosted on bitbucket and thus can't use Travis CI. Was thinking of using Circle CI in this case. Searched through the internet for examples of how to configure circle CI to deploy to openshift. Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: What are you wanting to deploy, a final image, or you just want to trigger a new build/deployment after some tests are run, with OpenShift still building the image?

Comment: I'm wanting to do the latter. Ideally, after Circle CI builds pass. It will call openshift and then openshift will build the image and deploy the application. If the build fails. Openshift isn't touched

Comment: Does Circle CI support triggering a webhook callback at the successful completion of a test?

Comment: BTW, you may find this blog post interesting. https://blog.openshift.com/using-generic-webhook-trigger-builds/ The problem with webhook callbacks on such systems is that they use their own format which doesn't work with OpenShift's generic webhook callback support. So you need to use a little proxy to interface between them.

Comment: Details of Circle CI webhook can be found at https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/configuration/#notify

Answer (score 0):

In this case you do not want to use automatic webhook based build triggering in Openshift based on accepted pull requests in GitHub, but just simply trigger a build by CircleCI via e.g. the Openshift (`oc start-build <buildconfig_name> --follow`) CLI tool.